# wpf combobox item template for the selected value and search functionality

Tags: wpf, combobox

I'm using a combobox in my application and I am populating it with classes something like this:

```
namespace Foo.Bar{
     public class Item
     {
          public string lastName;
          public string firstName;
          public Foo theMeatyPart;
     }
}
```

I can populate the dropdown with "lastName, firstName" using an itemTamplate but then the selected value shows up as "Foo.Bar.Item".  How can I apply the same template to the selectedItem and also, have the search functionality work without overrriding the ToString method of Item?

Here is the xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="SearchComboStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"></Setter>
                </Style.Setters>
            </Style>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="SearchComboItemTemplate" >
                    <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding}">
                            <TextBlock.Text>
                              <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}, {1}">
                                <Binding Path="lastName"/>
                                <Binding Path="firstName"/>
                              </MultiBinding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>


<ComboBox  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SearchComboItemTemplate}" Style="{StaticResource SearchComboStyle}" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PhysiciansList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:ExamViewerControl, AncestorLevel=1}}"      IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False" IsEditable="True" TextSearch.TextPath="Person.LastName" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UPD: <del>Looks like you need to set [SelectionBoxItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.selectionboxitemtemplate.aspx)</del>.

You can use [DisplayMemberPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath.aspx) or [TextSearch.TextPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textsearch.textpath.aspx) to enable search without modifying ToString().

Comment: Ooops. Sorry. What kind of ComboBox do you use? Is it editable?

Comment: System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox .NET 4.0

Comment: AFAIK, you can't change appearance of TextBox used in editable part of ComboBox, i.e. you can't apply DataTemplate. ComboBox use DisplayMemberPath or TextSearch.Path to set content on nested TextBox.

Comment: Can I apply the same multibinding to the displaymemberpath?

Comment: Unfortunately no. WPF internally use temporary Binding to an item with Path set to DisplayMemberPath (or PathText). But there are several ways that might help you. The first is to override ToString or add a property which work like MultiBinding. The second is to create a view-model for the Item class which wraps original item with additional property DisplayValue for example. The third is to wrap your items into DependencyObject where you can attach TextSearch.Text property. As for me, the second solution is best if you can't modify Item class.